# Using Provider in ExpansionPanelList

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider

I am trying to use provider with an ExpansionPanelList.
The issue is that I would need a new instance of provider for each ExpansionPanel but the ExpansionPanelList needs the expansionCallBack function which controls the state of the expansion `(bool isExpanded)`.

This is the sample code using setState and StatefulWidget, and I am trying to port this to provider.

```
class ExpansionPanelProvider {
  ExpansionPanelProvider({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;

  /*void updateExpansionState() {
      isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      notifyListeners();
  }*/

}

List<ExpansionPanelProvider> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return ExpansionPanelProvider(
      headerValue: 'Panel ${index + 1}',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number ${index + 1}',
    );
  });
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<ExpansionPanelProvider> _data = generateItems(80);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((ExpansionPanelProvider item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.expandedValue),
              subtitle: Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _data.removeWhere((currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                });
              }),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

This code uses set strings and data which is to be displayed. My data comes from another provider.

[EDIT]

I tried wrapping ExpansionPanel in a ChangeNotifierProvider, but that didn't work because ExpansionPanel can be a child of only ExpansionPanelList Widget.

Comment: Instead of create a list of providers, why not create a list of items for ExpansionPanel in a provider and set your ExpansionPanel listens to this list of items?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you though we code the difference.
I solved this by ADDING `extends ChangeNotifier` to a ExpansionPanelItem class.
[Like which did as Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html), Iterate the panel-item-class and wrap a `ChangeNotifierProvider.value(...)` around both `headerBulider` and `body` attributes in `ExpansionPanel`.

```
ExpansionPanel(
      canTapOnHeader: true,
      headerBuilder: (ctx, bool) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: item,
        child: _buildPanelHeader(item, index),
      ),
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: item,
        child: item.body,
      ),
      isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
    )
```

and then wrap `Consumer` around where you build your body and header like below:

```
// ...
Widget _buildPanelHeader(ExpansionPanelItem item, int index) {
return Consumer<ExpansionPanelItem>(
  builder: (ctx, itemRef, c) {
    return Container(
      // your header
    );
  }
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChangeNotifierProvider` on both the `headerBuilder` and `body` of the `ExpansionPanel`. That way you will still have the `ExpansionPanel` as the return type.

Be very careful with how much customization your widget will need. The trailing arrow from a `ExpansionPanel` can't be adjusted in the current version. I've swapped the `ExpansionPanel` to a `ExpansionTile` eventually.